# Can this be a correct way to set an inclusive scale?

Tags: java

Sorry this is my first post it might be vague and it might be not. Hopefully I can supply enough information. So:
I want to take a whole number from the user I know (int) of course but I want it to be from the scale 3 to 5 inclusive. 
Am I right in doing the following:

```
public Number(int enteranumber)
{
  enteranumber = 3;
}
```

does this mean that if the user tries to enter a number less than three then the field will automatically set to 3. And when the user enters a greater than 3 then the value of enteranumber will change to whatever the user put.
***I think this needs an if statement, but I don't think it's correct to have it in a constructor. That's what I have been told anyway***
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: The if statement can be before you call the constructor, and be the conditions you have specified, i.e. `if(number < 3 || number > 5){number = //Whatever default value} Number num = new Number(number);`

Comment: Please don't name your classes the same as core Java classes, it will only cause confusion.

Comment: I think it would be better practice to have a setter that has the constraint on `number`. That way you can call `setNumber(enteranumber);` that has the if statement of `if(number < 3 || number > 5){ this.number = defaultNumHere; } else { this.number = number; }` . This would make it so everytime you call the `setNumber` method you will guarantee that it will be the range of values you want.

Answer (score 0):

The current code snippet you have provided will overwrite the value of `enteranumber` to be 3 when a `new Number()` object is instantiated. No matter what is passed in that parameter, i.e. `new MyNumber(69)`, the constructor will overwrite the passed parameter immediately, that 69 to be 3 basically.

Being done inside the constructor is fine, if that is what you are wanting to do. Do you want the logic to run when you instantiate the object, or at a different time? If the former, then in the constructor is just fine. Here would be how you would do that

```
/**
 * Primary class
 */
class MyMainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyNumber number = new MyNumber(69);
        System.out.print(number.getEnterANumber()); // Output will be 5 in this scenario
    }
}

/**
 * Number POJO
 */
class MyNumber
{
    private int enteranumber_;

    public Number(int enteranumber) 
    {
        // Sets the value
        enteranumber_ = enteranumber;

        // Checks if the value is on the wrong side of 3
        if(enteranumber_ < 3)
        {
            // If it is, then sets the number to 3
            setEnterANumber(3);
        {

        // If you want the number to definitely be 3 - 5 inclusive
        else if(enteranumber_ > 5)
        {
            setEnterANumber(5);
        }
    }    

    // Modifier
    private static void setEnterANumber(int enteranumber)
    {
        enteranumber_ = enteranumber;
    {

    // Accessor
    public int getEnterANumber()
    {
        return enteranumber_;
    }    
}
```

The only time this `if else` block will change the value is if the passed value is 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped

Comment: Sorry just one more question out curiosity, because you explained the answer so well. When we say a number from "scale 4 to 6" inclusive that means an if statement correct?

Comment: That scale statement doesn't really have to do with an if statement, or programming in general. A number scale 4 to 6 inclusive means you can select numbers 4, 5, and 6 from that scale. Similarly, a number scale 0 to 10 inclusive would mean you could select 0, 1, 2, 3,...8, 9, 10. Now, a number scale 0 to 10 exclusive would mean you could select 1, 2, 3,..., 8, 9, but not numbers 0 or 10.